# Check the uniform convergence of $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left ( \frac{x \sin x}{1+x} \right )^k$ where $x \in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

Check the uniform convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left ( \frac{x \sin x}{1+x} \right )^k$ where $x \in [0,1]$.

**Solution i tried** - The  sequence of function has a contiunous limit   over given interval because $$\left ( \frac{x \sin x}{1+x} \right )^k \to 0\;\; \forall \;x \in [0,1]$$ after that i tried to take it as 
$$\left | \left ( \frac{x \sin x}{1+x} \right )^k \right | <\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^k$$ thus 
 here given 
$\displaystyle \sum \left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^k$ is a sum of  G.P with common ration $\frac{1}{2}$ then it will be convergent so the  given series is uniformaly   convergent by $M_n$ test  ,is every thing ok in my solution

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Seems to work fine.

Comment: Do not say that an equation is continuous. A function may be continuous. An equation is a sentence.

Comment: Not "equation"; it's a function.

Comment: Your reasoning for each summand being continuous is wrong.

Comment: @zhw i am not getting it can you please elaborate this?

Comment: You changed it and it makes sense now, but it shouldn't even be there. But you should mention why the inequality holds.